Unable to import .geojson Geometry to PostGis Database (null)
I`m trying to import geodata and the associated names from various regions within one .geojson file. Some geometries are Polygons, other Multipolygons.
Here is the start of the .geojson file:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "shapeName": "Stuttgart", "shapeISO": "", "shapeID": "9070358B86745718691241", "shapeGroup": "DEU", "shapeType": "ADM2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 8.768902291000074, 48.521841109000036 ], [ 8.769527448000076, 48.523685716000045 ], [ 8.771349093000026, 48.523480333000066 ], [ 8.771833428000036, 48.524333358000035 ], [ 8.777268014000072, 48.522360651000042 ], [ 8.781038882000075, 48.521310749000065 ], [ 8.784831049000047, 48.520892894000042 ], [...]

Full File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12sPpPsv_aQZFeD9qImgUmgPYZ4s9kUEn/view?usp=sharing
The Database Table is structured this way:
                                             Table "public.polygons_level_1"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------
 polygon_id  | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('polygons_level_1_polygon_id_seq'::regclass)
 region_name | character varying(150)      |           |          |
 geometry    | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |           |          |
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 centroid    | geometry(Point,4326)        |           |          | 

The issue:
The geometries are not imported. There are entries created for all 38 features, yet the "geometry" content is always "null".
My command is:
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=XXX user=XXX password=XXX port=XXX" \
-nln polygons_level_1 \
-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
-sql "SELECT shapeName AS region_name FROM level1_admin2" \
./level1_admin2.geojson

Note:

I`ve tried it both with and without the sql command for the region names - no difference to the main issue
The geodata is supposed to be stored in the database to be transmitted to MapBox when requested, as polygons.
-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry does not fix the issue

My Setup:

MacBook Pro M1 Pro
PostgreSQL 16.4

TLDR: Solution

Change SQL Prompt:

-sql "SELECT shapeName as region_name, geometry FROM level1_admin2" -dialect SQLite

Delete Index and create it again in database with USING GIST(geometry)clause, as before the byte size of the geodata would have been too large.


At least share a complete object in your Geo JSON sample data, to have a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Maybe if you add the modifier -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry (layer creation option) to your command in order to specify your table's geometry column name (destination). Since you have to geometries and could create confusion.

I have already tried using -lco GEOMETRY_NAME, with no change in the result. The data is meant to be appended to the existing "geometry" entry, therefore -lco commands only produce warnings (about creation options being ignored). The polygons are really big to post here. Here is the link to the complete .geojson (8MB), if that is ok. https://drive.google.com/file/d/12sPpPsv_aQZFeD9qImgUmgPYZ4s9kUEn/view?usp=sharing

Just specify the geometry name to serve as match to your table's geometry column, since your table has two geometry columns, as:
-sql "SELECT shapeName as region_name, geometry FROM level1_admin2" -dialect SQLite

adding additionally the sql dialect, because geometry name varies in different dialects.

Ok, now the data seems to be pulled. However now I get this error:
`
ERROR 1: ERROR:  index row requires 91160 bytes, maximum size is 8191
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR:  index row requires 91160 bytes, maximum size is 8191
Command: INSERT INTO "polygons_level_1" ("geometry" , "region_name") VALUES ('0106000020E61000[...]A06404840'::GEOMETRY, 'Stuttgart') RETURNING "polygon_id"
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer SELECT.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
`

Second Issue resolved: I had to drop the already automatically created Index of the entry and create it again using the USING GIST(geometry)  clause. Only after then would the ogr2ogr command import them correctly. Thank you for your help!
